# Circuit design to dimmer a 15W led with ESP32

Tags: led, pwm, esp32, dimmer

I'm new here! I'm designing an electronic circuit to control a led light (switch on/off and dimmer) in my room with homekit integration (iOS home).

So first of all I don't want to spend a lot of money for this, that is why I just want to use an ESP32 module with no Homebridge at all using this [library](https://github.com/Yurik72/ESPHap). Now the circuit needs to control a 15W led with this specs: 0.35A and 30-42V, and I have its driver that matches the specs. So surfing the internet I found [this](https://www.instructables.com/Circuits-for-using-High-Power-LED-s/) article, where it's explained many different ways to drive an high power LED including PWN which is what I'm looking for.

This is the circuit that I want to use:
[image]

with these components:
Q2: 2SK4017 Toshiba,
Q1: 2N5088BU,
Z1: 1N4733A,
R1: should have an high resistance if I'm not mistaken so 100k ohm 0.5W,
R3: 1.42 ohm 1W/2W

I'm going to hook up this circuit directly to the LED driver, and I'm powering the ESP32 with an usb powersupply. All of this makes sense in my mind and should work, but this my very first time doing a more "serious" project and I'll be glad if you can review this or maybe suggest me a better solution.

Comment: Q1 connecting your PWM output to ground is probably not a good idea for a start, you should at least limit the current with a resistor.

Comment: So if I put a 300ohm resistor just before Q1 collector I should be fine right? considering that ESP32 works with 3.3v and his maximum current on the GPIOs should be around 12mA

Comment: @Finbarr I forgot to tag you I'm sorry. I also forgot to mention that my driver is a constant current type, so would I be able to dim the LED like this?

Comment: Nothing about this circuit is appropriate for what you want. Driving one current source with another will have them fighting each other, meanwhile the R1/Z1 combination will be trying to drive 5.1V into an output trying to produce 3.3V or 0V.  The current through R3 will reduce the Vgs so that Q2 will barely turn on and, I suspect, no, the constant current supply won't like driving a load with PWM.